# Hostapd doesn't work consistently to set up access point

Tags: hostapd

I'm running hostapd on an embedded linux system with the following config file:

```
interface=wlan0
ssid=adhoctest
wep_key0="12345"
channel=1
hw_mode=g
driver=nl80211
```

But it only works some of the time.  Generally it works the first time after a fresh reboot, but if I close hostapd and start it again, it only works about half of the time.

The driver I'm using is rt2800usb.  I've tried unloading and reloading the kernel module with no affect.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Thanks!

Marlon

Edit: Here's some log info:

I can't see any difference in the hostapd logs between when it works and when it doesn't (running hostapd with -dd) except that when it's working, it constantly logs messages like this:

```
Add randomness: count=88 entropy=87
```

and when it's not working it sends out about 100 of those messages and then stops.

Looking at the wpa_supplicant logs on the client side, when it works the log looks like this:

```
nl80211: Authentication request send successfully
nl80211: Drv Event 19 (NL80211_CMD_NEW_STATION) received for wlan0
nl80211: New station 00:25:f0:51:72:99
nl80211: Drv Event 37 (NL80211_CMD_AUTHENTICATE) received for wlan0
nl80211: Authenticate event
```

and when it doesn't work, the log looks like this:

```
nl80211: Authentication request send successfully
nl80211: Drv Event 19 (NL80211_CMD_NEW_STATION) received for wlan0
nl80211: New station 00:25:f0:51:72:99
nl80211: Drv Event 20 (NL80211_CMD_DEL_STATION) received for wlan0
nl80211: Delete station 00:25:f0:51:72:99
nl80211: Drv Event 37 (NL80211_CMD_AUTHENTICATE) received for wlan0
nl80211: MLME event 37; timeout with 00:25:f0:51:72:99
```

Comment: When you say it "only works about half of the time", what does it do the other half of the time?  We need logs or other details.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the message with details!

Comment: You say that the driver you're using is rt2800usb but you've specified nl80211 as the driver in the config file. Could that be the issue?